# Changing the state of HTML Control on dropdown selection

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a detail page (Details.cshtml). And I have a dropdown list in that page. Upon selecting a value, it should change the state of few controls (Enabled or disabled). What I have done so far,

### In the View (details.cshtml)

```
 @Html.DropDownList("HighlightData", new SelectListItem[]
 {
   new SelectListItem() { Text = "None", Value = "0" },
   new SelectListItem() { Text = "On Demand Production", Value = "1" }
}, new { @onchange = "CallChangeUI(this.value)" })

<script>
  function CallChangeUI(state)
  {
    var productId = @(Model.ProductId);
    $.ajax({
      url: "/Product/ChangeUI",
      type: "POST",
      data: "id=" + productId + "&state=" + state,
      success :function() {
      },
      error   : function () {
      }
    });
  }
</script>


@Html.Partial("Display", Model  )
```

### In my controller

I have added this

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ChangeUI(int id, int state)
{
  return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = id });
}
```

The issue here is Details view only takes one parameter which is id. How do I pass the additional parameter "state" to Details so that I can enable/disable the control?

Is this the right approach? Or is there any other easier way to solve this problem?

-Alan-

### Updated

### Partial View (Display.cshtml)

```
 <div id="Details_@(territory.SalesTerritoryId)">
      <table class="formTable">
            <colgroup>
                <col class="width25" />
                <col class="width35" />
            </colgroup>
            <tr>
                <td class="display-label">@Html.LabelFor(t => t.Title.TitleId)</td>
                <td class="display-field">@Html.AuthorisedActionLink(Model.TitleId.ToString(), "Details", "Title", "Publishing", new { id = Model.TitleId }, null)</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
             </tr>
        </table>              
<div>
```

I would like to disable @Html.LabelFor(t => t.Title.TitleId) when the selection value is 1.

Comment: Why are you making an ajax call (as opposed to just changing the state of the controls on the current page). And ajax calls do not redirect so `return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = id });` is pointless.

Comment: I was thinking to repost the page and change the controls' state. Tell me if I am completely out of track

Comment: Update the view so show a couple of the other controls you want to disable so I can give you an answer (and you do realize disabled controls do not post back?)

Comment: Actually I missed a point here. I need to disable the controls in the partial view which is rendered in details view. I'll edit the question

Comment: What do you mean disable `@Html.LabelFor(t => t.Title.TitleId)` (you can disable a `<label>` element - its not a form control) and you don't even appear to have a form control for property `Title.TitleId` so why do you even have a `<label>` element?

Comment: What I mean was the text should "greyed" out. Looks like disabled.

Comment: Will add an answer to show how to do this all client side, but it does not make sense - a `<label>` is an element associated with a form control (clicking on it sets focus to the associated control) so it really should be just a `<span>` or `<div>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to make a call to the server to do this (and in any case, ajax calls do not redirect, so `return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = id });` is a bit pointless.

Stop polluting your mark up with behavior and use [Unobtrusive Javascript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)

```
@Html.DropDownList("HighlightData", new SelectListItem[]
{
  new SelectListItem() { Text = "None", Value = "0" },
  new SelectListItem() { Text = "On Demand Production", Value = "1" }
})

$('#HighlightData').change(function() {
  if ($(this).val() == 1) {
    $(.display-label').addClass('disabled');
  } else {
    $(.display-label').removeClass('disabled');
  }
});
```

Note the script is applying the class to the `<td>` element and assumes you will not be using a `<label>` as noted below (otherwise it could be `$(.display-label').children('label').addClass('disabled')`;)

and use css to style the element, for example

```
.disabled label {
  color: grey;
}
```

Note the script will change all elements with `class="display-label"` so you may want to give the elements `id` attributes if you need something more specific. And since your element is not acting as a label (there is no associated form control to set focus), the element should really be a `<span>` or `<div>` or just text within the `<td>`, for example

```
<td class="display-label">@Html.DisplayFor(t => t.Title.TitleId)</td>
```